# Copying an immutable Array or Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a couple of functions in a javascript project that accept an object as an argument and are expected to return a copy of this object with a few changes. I'm trying to make these functions immutable, but the argument can be either an Object or an Array, so I can't just use `Object.assign({}, original)` or `{...original}`.

Instead, I've come up with a couple of options:

```
let doSomething = function doSomething(original) {
    let ret = Object.assign(Array.isArray(original) ? [] : {}, original);

    //OR
    let ret = Array.isArray(original) ? [...original] : {...original};

    //OR
    let ret = Object.assign(new (original.constructor), original);

    //OR
    let ret;

    if(Array.isArray(original))
        ret = original.slice();
    else
        ret = Object.assign({}, original);

    //make changes

    return ret;
}
```

Out of the four, my preference would be for the third method, just because it supports any type of object (not that I plan on using anything other than Objects or Arrays), but it feels "clever" in a bad way.

Out of the four methods, which is best for readability? Or is there another preferred way to copy any type of Object?

Comment: would it be enough to copy just members? or is it needed to copy prototype and constructor also? also I believe #3 will not work once object's constructor expects arguments.

Comment: This seems like an X/Y issue, why is one function taking two different types to copy. [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: for some context @DLowther, `doSomething` is a recursive function that's being called with what are essentially JSON objects (AWS thing shadow documents). I'd argue that Arrays and Objects are similar enough to be considered one type in this context, and the function is only being called to carry out a single task on the actual JSON object.

Comment: @skyboyer copying members would be good enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options #1, #2 and #4 are doing completely the same. As for readability my vote is for #2 - shortest and clearest.

Option #3 also recreates constructor/prototype chain that is not you need in this case. It will allow to run check like `copiedObj instanceof OriginalObjectClass`. But it also may fail once constructor expects some arguments(and does not get them obviously). So in your case it looks rather dangerous approach than helpful.

Also I completely agree with D Lowther it would be better to extract cloning itself from your recursive function.

But I guess that you don't only want to clone some object but also process clone's nested property recursively. And this way you will also require to check if this object or array, right? So instead of cloning array separately and then cloning its members it would be easier to do that in one line with `.map`:

```
function cloneRecursively(originalItem) {
    let clonedItem = {...originalItem};
    clonedItem.children = (clonedItem.children || []).map(cloneRevursively);
    return clonedItem;
}
```

Comment: there are few things that happen to the copies as well, so I won't be able to use `.map`, but you raise some good points about the different options in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `constructor` method instead of `new (original.constructor)`!

As your param can be an `object` or an `array`, you could simply write it like this:

`let ret = Object.assign(original.constructor(), original)`

Calling it like that, will return an empty `object` or `array`.

Be aware that if your param is not a plain JS `object`, using `constructor` would either fail or return something unexpected